# Summing Diagonal Elements of Matrix in Octave

Tags: matrix, octave, diagonal

Given a square matrix `M`, how can you find the sum of the elements on the diagonal?  There must be an easier method than this:

`sum(sum(diag(diag(M), 0)))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, what I was looking for was the trace:

```
1> M = reshape(1:9, 3, 3)
M =

   1   4   7
   2   5   8
   3   6   9

2> trace(M)
ans =  15
```

Answer (score 7):

Just `sum(diag(M))` seems to work fine.

```
1> M = reshape(1:9, 3, 3)
M =

   1   4   7
   2   5   8
   3   6   9

2> sum(diag(M))
ans =  15
```